# PHP Use select value to search and display result to textbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, search

My Selectbox Items from aircraft table

```
<select name="selectaircraft">
<option id="0">-- Select Aircraft -- </option>
<?php
require("dbc.php");
$getallaircraft = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aircrafttable");
while($viewallaircraft = mysql_fetch_array($getallaircraft)){
?>
<option id="<?php echo $viewallaircraft['ID']; ?>">
<?php echo $viewallaircraft['aircraft'] ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

hi guys im trying to use the the value of selectaircraft to search and display the result to textbox.. here is my code so far

```
<?php
   require("dbc.php");
       $getallconfig = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aircrafttable WHERE aircraft LIKE 'PR200'");  
   while($viewallconfig= mysql_fetch_array($getallconfig)){

?>
   <input type="text" name="aconfig "value="<?php echo $viewallconfig['config'];      ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

As you can see, I only put PR200 to search, my question is how can i use the select value instead? I also want the search query to happen everytime i click the select box.

guys can some1 help me? i know how to code this in VB6 it will be like this

assume : select name or in VB6 combobox = selectbox

```
Private Sub Combo3_Click()
adodc1.recorsource ="Select * from aircrafttable where aircraft = " & selectbox & "'"
adodc1.refresh


Text1.Text = Adodc1.Recordset("aircraft")
```

everytime i click combo/selectbox the query will perform and give different answer to textbox.
i dont know how to do this in PHP pls help!

Edited Added all codes

```
    <form action="addrecord.php" method="post" >


    <table border=1>
    <tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
    <strong>Area:</strong> </td>
    <td>

 <input type="text" required="required" name="aarea" size=10 /><br /></td></tr>

    <tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
    <strong>Aircraft:</strong></td>





<td>

<form method="post" action="aircraft.php">
 <select name="selectaircraft" onchange="this.form.submit();">
     <option id="0">Aircraft</option>
<?php
      require("dbc.php");
      $getallaircraft = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aircrafttable");
      while($viewallaircraft = mysql_fetch_array($getallaircraft)){
?>
      <option id="<?php echo $viewallaircraft['ID']; ?>">
<?php 
      echo $viewallaircraft['aircraft'] ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
    </select>



<?php
        require("dbc.php");
        if(isset($_POST)){
        $takeaircraft = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selectaircraft']);     

{

?>
   <input type="text" name="aaircraft" size=3 value="<?php echo $takeaircraft;  ?>" />
<?php } 
}?>


</form>


</td></tr>

<tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
<strong>Flight:</strong> </td>
 <td><input type="text"  name="aflight" size=10  /><br /></td></tr>

 <tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
<strong>Configuration:</strong> </td>
 <td>



 <?php
        require("dbc.php");
        if(isset($_POST)){
        $selectaircraft = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selectaircraft']);     
         $getallconfig = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aircrafttable WHERE aircraft LIKE '".$selectaircraft."'"); 
 while($viewallconfig= mysql_fetch_array($getallconfig)){

?>
   <input type="text" name="aconfig" value="<?php echo $viewallconfig['config'];      ?>" />
<?php } 
}?>

 <br /></td></tr>
  <tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
<strong>Month:</strong> </td>
 <td>
 <select name="amonth">
        <option value="na">Month</option>
        <option value="January">January</option>
   </select>
 </td></tr>

 <tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
<strong>Frequency:</strong> </td>
 <td><span style="font-size:11px; font-weight:bolder" >

    Mon<input type="checkbox" id='check1' onClick='checkmon()'>
<input type="hidden"  id="txt1" name="hiddenmon" value="n/a">


   Tue<input type="checkbox" id='check2' onClick='checktue()'>
<input type="hidden"  id="txt2" name="hiddentue" value="n/a">

   Wed<input type="checkbox" id='check3' onClick='checkwed()'>
<input type="hidden"  id="txt3" name="hiddenwed"  value="n/a">


   Thu<input type="checkbox" id='check4' onClick='checkthu()'>
<input type="hidden"  id="txt4" name="hiddenthu" value="n/a">

  Fri<input type="checkbox" id='check5' onClick='checkfri()'>
<input type="hidden"  id="txt5" name="hiddenfri"  value="n/a">

  Sat<input type="checkbox" id='check6' onClick='checksat()'>
<input type="hidden"  id="txt6" name="hiddensat"  value="n/a">

  Sun<input type="checkbox" id='check7' onClick='checksun()'>
<input type="hidden"  id="txt7" name="hiddensun" value="n/a">


 </span>
 <br /></td></tr>



<tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
<strong>Menu:</strong> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="amenu" size=10 /><br /></td></tr>



<tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
<strong>Cycle:</strong> </td>
 <td>
 <select name="acycle">
        <option value="na">Cycle</option>
        <option value="Cycle 1">Cycle 1</option>

        </select>


<tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
<strong>Items:</strong> </td>
 <td>
 <select name="aitem">
        <option value="na">Items</option>

                </select>



<tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
<strong>STD Time:</strong> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="astdtime" size=5 /><br /></td></tr>


<tr><td bgcolor="#999999">
<strong>Quantity:</strong> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="aqty" size=5 /><br /></td></tr>


<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="right" bgcolor="#999999">
<input type='submit' name="add" value="Add Records" />
</td>
</tr>
 </table>



    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trigger submit on change of select box as below

```
<form action="path/to/your/query/file.php" method="post"> //if query in same page leave your action blank
   <select name="selectaircraft" onchange="this.form.submi();">
     <option id="0">-- Select Aircraft -- </option>
<?php
      require("dbc.php");
      $selected_aircraft=isset($_POST['selectaircraft'])?$_POST['selectaircraft']:"";
      $getallaircraft = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aircrafttable");
      while($viewallaircraft = mysql_fetch_array($getallaircraft)){
      $selectstr="";
      if($selected_aircraft==$viewallaircraft['aircraft'] ){
         $selectstr="selected='selected'";
      }

?>
      <option id="<?php echo $viewallaircraft['ID']; ?>" <?php echo $selectstr ?> >
<?php 
             echo $viewallaircraft['aircraft'] ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

and change you query as below:

```
 <?php
        require("dbc.php");
        if(isset($_POST)){
        $selectaircraft = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selectaircraft']);     
         $getallconfig = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aircrafttable WHERE aircraft LIKE '{ $selectaircraft}'"); 
 while($viewallconfig= mysql_fetch_array($getallconfig)){

?>
   <input type="text" name="aconfig "value="<?php echo $viewallconfig['config'];      ?>" />
<?php } 
}?>
```

**Update** updated code to maintain state of select box.

Comment: hello actually i dont know how to put code onchange :( where exactly ill put this? ty

Comment: hi thanks. but i dont want my form to submit everytime i change select box. i just want to automatically give value to my config textbox. which is came from the config equals of aircraft i choose.

Comment: hi it works but the selectbox return to ---Select Aircraft--- everytime i click it. seems like refreshing

Comment: you mean you want to maintain stat of select box

Comment: Hi i added all my codes. as you can see i have lots of field when the user fill up some field and click the select box with the query this.form.submit all textfield will be clear seems like refreshing. do you have any work around? thank you so much!

Comment: wrap all your field inside the form, then use below like code for all your field to maintain stat
`<input type="text" required="required" <?php echo isset($_POST['aarea'])?$_POST['aarea']:"" ?> name="aarea" size=10 />`

Comment: hi <input type="text" required="required" <?php echo isset($_POST['aarea'])?$_POST['aarea']:"" ?> name="aarea" size=10 /> this code wont hellp :(. still everytime i click the selectbox the form is refreshing and all fields go back to their initial state. i am planning to put 2 selectbox... but super thank you for some code it does help me alot

Comment: have you embed you field in side form? do like this

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
$aircraft = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['selectaircraft']);  //or $_GET

$getallconfig = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM aircrafttable WHERE aircraft LIKE '".$aircraft."'");
```

Comment: Hi, i want the search query to happen everytime i click the selecbox. is that possible?

Comment: Do you want to refresh the result in `onchange` of the select box..?

Comment: im actually want the config result to be automatic when i select the aircraft.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the select box(1st) inside a form , on change submit the form to the next page .

And get the POST/GET value , and use it for select query for searching.